# Why doesn't the kitten example in the Chrome extension development tutorial load any images?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the [Getting Started](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) page, we're promised kittenish goodness from Flickr. Putting the extension together according to the instructions, no kittenish goodness materializes. Instead, the popup window shows a small blank rectangular bar, devoid of anything fuzzy or cute.

Why?

(I'm asking this question with the intent to answer it, because I couldn't find any other way to report the mistake.)

Comment: The Getting started tutorial no longer uses Flickr's kittens, but Google Image search, see: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=383385#c5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bug in the popup.js file on line 40. The reference to kittensOnFlickr_ should be searchOnFlickr_ instead. Fix and reload, and tada, kitteh.

Comment: Oh.. No.. this question was asked 25 mins ago, and the @Emerson's answer was 23 mins ago, and I struggled for 30 mins!! to find out this error! No matter who made that change, I'd like to say: "Damn you!"

Comment: I had to write the question before I could answer it. :)

Comment: Note that this bug has already been fixed a while back: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172849

Comment: Ugh... So what if I face the problem again?

Comment: Well, seems API key has expired :/ See https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-extensions/dXmRdgY1Wgg/X9QCIyjfj0UJ

Answer (score 8):

As on 18-Jun-2014, the fix mentioned by Emerson seems to be taken care of in the sample downloads.

If you are still not able to see the images in the popup, you should consider applying for a [Flickr API Key](https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply)

And replace the existing key with the key that you generated in line number 25 of `poupup.js` file.

Answer (score 2):

**8/1/2014** - The code on line has indeed been fixed, but this tutorial still wouldn't work for me until I pasted my own API key.

**HOWEVER**

Make sure you don't remove the trailing ampersand (the `&`) at the end of the pasted api key. The ampersand needs to be there or your code still won't work!

Comment: Opened a new bug for the API key issue: [http://crbug.com/399801](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=399801)